# I have these commands, which one is making my table of contents not clickable?

Tags: table-of-contents

What do I have to remove or add here to make my table of contents clickable, such that when you click on a chapter it takes you to that chapter/section etc.? I have written other documents where it did this automatically, and I remember adding something here that removed that function. I don't know what exactly.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{float}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={6in, 8in}]{geometry}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }
\newcommand{\degree}{\ensuremath{^\circ}}
\newcommand{\quotes}[1]{``#1''}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[columns=3, title=Alphabetical Index, intoc]
\usepackage[spanish,es-nodecimaldot]{babel}
\usepackage[sorting=none]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Bibfile.bib}
\DeclareMathOperator\grad{grad}
\DeclareMathOperator\prima{'}
\DeclareMathOperator\sen{sen}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{position=bottom}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[per-mode=symbol]{siunitx}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\usepackage{longtable}
\interfootnotelinepenalty=10000
\usepackage[spanish]{minitoc}
```

Comment: Add \usepackage{hyperref} to your preamble and read the hyperref manual.

Comment: Also make sure to load the `hyperref` package LAST in the list of packages UNLESS another package explicitly requires to be loaded after `hyperref`. `cleveref` would be one such package.